# Windows 10 PC suddenly goes into black screen (the red light in the mouse also goes off)

Tags: windows-10

I am facing a disruptive issue after building a new PC, which is completely random and sometimes doesn't happen for an entire week:

When it occurs, I can see the PC is still on, with all the fans on as usual (CPU fan's lights are on), but the monitor, keyboard, and mouse are suddenly turned off.

- I checked Event Viewer and all I see is the following message, which seems understandable as I turned off the PC after it stopped being responsive:

  ```
  The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. 
  This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly
  ```
- RAM test completed without any problems

---

Specs:

- Motherboard: ASUS B450M-A
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 2700x
- RAM: Crucial Ballistix Sport LT BLS2K8G4D32AESBK 3200 MHz (x2)
- GPU: ASUS DUAL RX580 O4G OC Edition 4GB
- PSU: Corsair [TX650M](https://www.corsair.com/it/it/Categorie/Prodotti/Alimentatori/txm-series-2017-config/p/CP-9020132-EU)
- HDD: 1TB WD

Comment: Your computer is hard resetting. This is usually a hardware fault. Because it isn't giving a BSOD I'd guess the power supply may be faulty or insufficient. Please provide a full list of the hardware you used to build the computer.

Comment: Hi @music2myear .. I've just edited my post as previously I didn't pay too much attention to arrange the components names in a list ..

Comment: What power supply?

Comment: Does the hard reset coincide with anything else, like a microwave oven being switched on, or air conditioning, or a washing machine, etc.?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton .. I would say no .. beacause it happened yesterday when all that was turned on was a TV and this PC in the entire house ..

Comment: @TheOnePar I suggest re-making all the connections, just to be sure there isn't a slightly loose connector in there. Then do you have any components you could swap in, e.g. another graphics card?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton, I had already tried reconnecting everything but I faced the issue anyway... In fact I am thinking it is not a issue of cables because the PC does work as it should be without any problem.. the only major issue at that moment when it just enters in a strange "sleep mode" (before that moment I realize that the screen for a moment "hangs" and then after like 1 sec happens all those issues reported above in the post)

Comment: Hi guys, I've just replaced the psu (same model as listed above) with a new one and it worked normally for 2 hours until I rebooted it for a Windows update and when it was near the login screen (after the reboot) it did that black screen again ... I really can't get my head around this thing..

Comment: @music2myear what do you guys suggest me to do.. I am just really mad and I am unable to find a solution (could it be the RX580? Could it be the motherboard? Or that model of psu just doesn't suit for my build?) Thanks in advance

Comment: It could be anything. It is very difficult to diagnose hardware issues remotely. If this is getting past your ability or patience, you should take it to a qualified local hardware technician for analysis and repair.